# jquery ajax request return status 0 with chrome, but works fine with IE8

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, status

I am trying to use jquery/ajax to pull some data from server. The ajax status returned from chrome is 0, but IE8 works fine.

I am banging my head about this issue. I am not doing any crossing web server stuff and tried to use absolute url.

Any other thing to check?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, the best I can do is point you to the following resources and hope you'll see something that looks similar to your setup:

- [jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)
- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/282972
- http://markos.gaivo.net/blog/?p=109
- http://developsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/10/google-chrome-xmlhttprequest-behaviour.html

Note that the issues are usually cross-site requests or using `file:///` instead of `http[s]://`

Answer (score 0):

try 'return false' at the end of the ajax code in case you are using image instead of button element to submit the form. Worked for me.