# Ajax Status Returning 0 on Abort

Tags: c#, ajax, status

I have an ajax status which I abort. It returns a status code of 0. Would this be indicative of the abort or of some other conflict?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0, also might be timeout.

Comment: @MennanKara I'm not cross-site ajaxing, but I'm wondering if the "unreachable url" might be tripped when an ajax is abort since it didn't technically have time to reach the url. Thoughts?

Comment: Might be, ajax requests have a timeout value (see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and when if there is no response at the timeout it returns status 0 and you can see it as canceled on firebug.

Comment: @MennanKara Never used firebug. Mind giving me a link?

Comment: Install Firefox then add Firebug addon from Firefox menu / Add-Ons / Get Addons

Comment: @MennanKara Bugger. I'm developing for IE7 only. (not by choice. It's an industry standard in my office)

Comment: You can still use firebug for debugging.