# JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest response status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to fetch data from an XML file to a JS variable (I would like to use pure JS, no jQuery). But I have always get error while downloading the file:

```
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(event){ processRequest(event,xmlhttp); };
xmlhttp.send();

function processRequest(event,xmlhttp) {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
    alert("status: " +xmlhttp.status);
}
```

The response xml is always empty - the response status is 0.

Comment: Did you checked these answers here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because it violates the **Same origin policy.**

Do:

1. GO to w3School website.
2. Open developer console.
3. Paste and run your code and you will get the result

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is just strange that the browser itself can send crossDomain requests (e.g. simply opening the url), but JS is not able to do so.

Comment: _DON'T_ go to w3schools, Please, don't. [here's why](http://w3fools.com/). I'd recommend either quirksmode or MDN for good, reliable documentation... or even JavaScriptKit

Answer (score 1):

Try local url. Your code doesn't match [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

p.s. w3schools is not where you want to learn, mdn and dochub.io ;)