# jQuery $.ajax method displays error status

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, html, web-services

the webservice looks like

```
using System;<br/>
using System.Collections.Generic;<br/>
using System.Linq;<br/>
using System.Web;<br/>
using System.Web.Services;<br/>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]<br/>
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]<br/>
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] <br/>
public class Map : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   [WebMethod]
    public MapClass LatitudeLongitude()
    {
       MapClass mapobj = new MapClass();
       return mapobj;

    }
     [WebMethod]
  public string helloToYou() 
  { 

      return "Hello"; 
 } 

}
```

the class look like:

```
public class MapClass <br/>
{

    string latitude;

    string longitude;

    public MapClass()

    {

        latitude = "51.508742";
        longitude = "-0.120850";
    }

}
```

And i am trying to call the webservice from a html5 page

```
`</head>`<br/>
`<body>`<br/>

`<form id="form1" runat="server">`<br/>

`<h1>Map</h1>`<br/>

`<input id="View" type="button" value="Click to view" onclick="getData()"/>`<br/>

`</form>`<br/>

`</body>`<br/>


`<script type="text/javascript" src="D:\PepsiCO\jQuery\jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>`<br/>

`<script type="text/javascript">`

    function getData() {

       $.ajax({

          type:"POST",
          url: "http://localhost:53788/HTML5_WebService_Maps/Map.asmx/helloToYou",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
            complete: function (response)
            { alert('complete'); },
            success: function (response)
           { alert('Success'); },
            error: function (response)
            { alert('Failure'); }
        });
    }
`</script>`
`</html>`
```

when i browse the html page in chrome, it displays failure in alert box. Dont know why it isnt showing success. Please help.

Comment: try adding `data: '{}',` to your ajax function. Not sure if it will work though.

Comment: make sure your server returning content type `application/json`

Comment: also set url to `url: "Map.asmx/helloToYou",`

Comment: @munnebShabbir how to check whether the server is returning content type 'application/json'

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @user2404699 type this in your web browser `http://localhost:53788/Map.asmx` and check if your webservice can be called from an ajax function. It will show you a page with all the `webmethods` if your webservice is accessible and correctly defined.

Comment: @Rune FS  I tried to load the html page in IE. The status text is No response. status is 0. response text is undefined

Comment: @thunderbird i tried to access http://localhost:53788/HTML5_WebService_Maps/Map.asmx. I get a page with all accessible webmethods. http://localhost:53788/Map.asmx throws 404 error. how to check whether the webservice can be called from ajax function?

Comment: @user2404699  go to your `.asmx` markup page(rightclick the page in the solution explorer and select view markup) and add `~/` to the `codebehind` attribute(prefix it). you can access the webservice by setting your `url` to `"HTML5_WebService_Maps/Map.asmx/helloToYou"`

Comment: <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Map.cs" Class="Map" %>  I hope this is what you meant  @thunderbird

Comment: @user2404699 yes. are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: @user2404699 shouldn't the class attribute be defined like this `projectname.Map`

Answer (score 0):

Try appending this to the webmethod:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And return object with serializer:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string strJSON = js.Serialize(mapobj);
return strJSON;
```

Also it might be a good idea to post the error response:

```
error: ajaxFailed

function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
$('#errordiv).html(xmlRequest.status + ' <br /> ' +
            xmlRequest.statusText + '<br />' +
            xmlRequest.responseText);
}
```

In response to your comment on this answer:
Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/users/158502/langdon 'In my experience, you'll see a status of 0 when either doing cross-site scripting (where access is denied) or requesting a URL that is unreachable (typo, DNS issues, etc).'

[jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)

Comment: You don't have to serialize data that has to be returned. asp.net does it automatically for you.

Comment: status is **0**; statusText is**error**; responsetext is **blank**

Comment: In my experience, you'll see a status of 0 when either doing cross-site scripting (where access is denied) or requesting a URL that is unreachable (typo, DNS issues, etc). Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Comment: I tried to load the html page in IE. The status text is **No response**. status is **0**. response text is **undefined**

Comment: If you host the webservice on IIS in different app (so diff ports) than your html5 page, you are making cross-domain request, which gives problems like described in the linked question. What if you deploy your html5 page to the same app?

Comment: the html page from which i am trying to access the web service is in different application.

Comment: So that is your problem then. See this for possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10618640/2215083

Comment: @Yeronimo I got the data from webservice when i browse in IE. But chrome still gives error status

Answer (score 0):

change dataType to htmland check

```
dataType: "html",
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your web page running on the same domain / port ? What is the status code of the response ?

Comment: what about the domain / port ? any entries in the chrome console ?

Comment: the webpage i have created is a simple html5 page, that i browse from visual studio 2010. i havent hosted the service in IIS.

Comment: I tried to load the html page in IE. The status text is No response. status is 0. response text is undefined

Comment: The status text is No Transport