# Ajax not reaching 'success' for login form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The success part of the ajax function is never reached.  I've spent hours on it, still no success.  The code has been stripped of virtually everything necessary just to try and remove any possible problems but it still doesn't work.

Below is the stripped out code that I'm trying to get to work.  Thanks for any help.

Ajax:

```
function validLogin(){

    var url = "loginProcessAjax.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,

        beforeSend: function() {
            //
            alert("sdfs");
        },

        success: function(html) {

            alert("success");
            alert(html.getElementsByTagName("worked")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        },

        error: function( error ) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: text/xml");
 echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
 echo "<worked>";
 echo "success";
 echo "</worked>";
 ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ourLoginFormID_JS">
                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" autocomplete="off" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="required"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label> &nbsp; </label>
                        <input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login!" onclick="validLogin()"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="statusLogin"></div>
                </form>
```

In beforeSend, the alert box with xml doesn't get generated.  the other one does so I know it's at least calling the function.

Comment: Open your browser's debugger (F-12) and look at the network traffic. See what your server response is.

Comment: Maybe your alert is silently failing - you said so yourself, so the processing is stopped. What do you get if you alert only "html"?

Comment: Check your loginProcessAjax.php on browser directly. I think that you have php short open tag enabled and the first echo fails

Comment: "In beforeSend, the alert box with xml doesn't get generated. the other one does so I know it's at least calling the function." You edited your question to remove the second alert. So what is the problem now?

Comment: @JasonP Sorry about that, didn't see it! Although looking at the other deleted answer now, they had that in their answer

Comment: @Diodeus is there anything in particular I should be looking for?  I see that the js file is called but not the specific  function but clearly it is.

Comment: @JasonP Yeah, that was sleep deprivation and desperation kicking in:)

Comment: @chumkiu the url displays the same results if I leave the closing tag or remove it.

Comment: Your ajax pretty much works http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/2j6qY/1/

Comment: @Spokey Can you elaborate?  The XML displays fine when using URL

Comment: @SteveGreen nothing my bad.

Comment: @Spokey Would you mind showing an example of using an echo or a json to get the data instead of xml please? Also just realised that the PHP may not be getting called.

Comment: @SteveGreen depends on what kind of json format you're looking for. Could you give a more specific data example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33774/discussion-between-steve-green-and-spokey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spokey solved this in chat. Legend.

```
by using $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'loginProcessAjax.php',
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert("sent");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html) 
    },
    error: function( x, status, error ) {
        alert(x.status + status + error);
    }
});
```

we were able to get an error code which then led to

[jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)

which then in turn led to a couple of things.  Firstly as espascarello pointed out the form was not returning false so it was resending the data.
With that amended the url was not found which was odd so using an absolute path solve it.

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: @epascarello I know :) But it doesn't like the relative one.  I've put it into the same folder, tried moving it to where it belongs, all sorts but just...no.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the form submission from happening

change

```
onclick="validLogin()"/>
```

to

```
onclick="validLogin(); return false;"/>
```

it would be better to use `onsubmit` on the form and not a click event on the button. It would be even better to not use inline event handlers.

Comment: Do you mean giving it an ID and then targeting that with the JS?

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: I am not sure where you came up with an ID since I never mentioned an id in my post. So you called return false and nothing happened?

Comment: The form is refreshing, it cancel the Ajax call. You will not get a response. You need to cancel the form submission! You need to return false on the click like I showed.

Comment: :) No I meant to use ID in response to you mentioning not using inline  handlers.  You are right though.