# AJAX queries failing for exactly 60 seconds per time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript function that runs every 5 seconds and requests information from the same server via a **jQuery AJAX call**. The function runs indefinitely once the page is loaded.

For some reason the AJAX query is failing about once every minute or two, and showing

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

in the console. The odd thing is, it fails for exactly 60 seconds, then starts working fine for another minute or two.

So far I've tried with no success:

- Different browser
- Different internet connection
- Changing the polling time of the function. (Still fails for 60 second intervals. eg run every 10 seconds, it fails 6 times. Or 5x12 or 1x60)
- Web searches which suggesting flushing ip settings on my computer

I never had any problem on my last server which was a VPS. I'm now running this off shared hosting with GoDaddy and wonder if there's a problem at that end. Other sites and AJAX calls to the server are working fine during downtimes though.

I also used to run the site over HTTPS, now it's over plain HTTP only. Not sure if relevant.

Here's the guts of the function:

```
var interval = null;
function checkOrders() {
interval = window.setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://www.chipshop.co.nz/ajax/check_orders.php",
      data: {shopid : 699},
      error: function(errorData) {
        //handle error
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //handle success
      }
    });
}, 5000); // repeat until switched off, polling every 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: check the network tab and see what is the request and response properties...

Comment: Please share your controller code here, it looks like you using Magento

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but why do you use `POST` to check for orders? You aren't creating any new resources, you should use `GET` here

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo Not using Magneto, just PHP. Have removed the PHP parts for clarity.

Comment: @maximf Good point - the example in jQuery docs used POST so I always used it also!

Comment: @ArunPJohny the network tab is returning status code 200 on successful AJAX calls along with the required info. On failed attempts, the following is shown in the Chrome network tab: `Request headers:Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://www.chipshop.co.nz
Referer:http://www.chipshop.co.nz/control-panel?shopid=699
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` - The status comes back as (failed)

Comment: Also on failed AJAX calls, the console is showing `POST http://www.chipshop.co.nz/ajax/check_orders.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}`

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue. did you get a resolution?

Answer (score 3):

**Solved:** It turned out the problem was with GoDaddy hosting. Too many POST requests resulted in the 60 second 'ban' from accessing that file. Changing to GET avoided this.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0) contains the answer from user emrys57 :

> For me, the problem was caused by the hosting company (Godaddy)
>   treating POST operations which had substantial response data (anything
>   more than tens of kilobytes) as some sort of security threat. If more
>   than 6 of these occurred in one minute, the host refused to execute
>   the PHP code that responded to the POST request during the next
>   minute. I'm not entirely sure what the host did instead, but I did
>   see, with tcpdump, a TCP reset packet coming as the response to a POST
>   request from the browser. This caused the http status code returned in
>   a jqXHR object to be 0.
>
> Changing the operations from POST to GET fixed the problem. It's not
>   clear why Godaddy impose this limit, but changing the code was easier
>   than changing the host.

Comment: It actually blocks the whole website from working for anyone until that 1 minute ban is over. Sounds like an easy way for anyone to take down a GoDaddy website by continuing to send POST data to the website. This is not acceptable for any Host.

Comment: I meant it only bans our ip address and any computer that has that ip address.