# XHR doesn't get the proper status code

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is a server-side function that receives a POST request and handles its response. As you can see, when no error occurs, the status code of the response is 200.

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.serialize(function() {
            db.run("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            [req.query['email'], req.query['company'], req.query['subject'], req.query['text']],
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject();
                } else {
                    console.log("Transaction passed");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    p.then(function(){
        res.status(200).end();
    }).catch(function() {
        res.status(400).end();
    })
});
```

In the client side, I wrote a JS function that sends an AJAX POST request to the server and handles the response:

```
function addFormToDB(email, company, subject, text) { 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text;
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit?" + params, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xhttp.readyState + " " + xhttp.status);
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log("request " + params + " was sent to DB");
            alert("Thank You!");
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
}
```

When I invoke the function 'addFormToDB' from the console window of the browser, it sends an AJAX request to the server and gets it back with an xhhr.status of 200.

However, 'addFormToDB' has to be invoked when the user fills a form and clicks the 'submit' button. When this happens, the xhhr.status sent back from the server to the browser is always 0. I don't know why.

Here is the HTML code that creates the form:

```
<form id="form">
        <label for="email"> E-mail: </label>
        <input id = "email"> <br>
        <label for="company"> Company: </label>
        <input id = "company"> <br>
        <label for="subject"> Subject: </label>
        <input id = "subject"> <br>
        <label for="text"> Text: </label>
        <input id = "text"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button"><br><br>
    </form>
...
<script>
$("#form").submit(function() {
    addFormToDB($("#email").val(), $("#company").val(), $("#subject").val(), $("#text").val())
});
</script>
```

Can you help me find out the bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://i.imgur.com/27bhIwa.png

Comment: OK. What invokes the function addFormToDB is a button click.
I have an html form with a button, once the button is clicked, inputs of the form are read and then the function addFormToDB is called. Probably the problem is with the button click.... Do you have any idea?

Comment: `xhttp.status is always 0` doesn't it means it can't connect to the host? [related, http status code 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)

Comment: `the status xhttp.status is always 0`- could also be CORS - the fact that the request is to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` suggests it's to a different host than the page is served from

Comment: You have to `send(params)` not `open(url + params)`

Comment: But, how will the server know that the request is for '/sumbit'?
It works without the button. It doesn't make sense that this is the solution.

Comment: `xhr.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit'); ... xhr.send(params);` + you could simplify everything by just doing `xhr.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit'); xhr.send(new Formdata(document.getElementById('form'));`.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't help :(

Comment: You currently do not properly encode your request parameters. You can't simply build a query string with string concatenation. You *must* call `encodeURIComponent()` on every value you want to transfer. Either that, or use a Ajax library that abstracts away the busywork (jQuery Ajax, reqwest, just pick one). Solve this problem first before you do anything else.

Comment: But why does it happen specifically when I invoke the function by pressing the 'submit' button?

Comment: Do you prevent traditional form transmit (the one where the page reloads) in your submit handler? My guess is that you don't.

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of your `submit` event listener.

Comment: @jcaron, Hallelujah! It works!
If you want, write an answer to this post, and I promise I'll accept it.

Comment: Credit should go to @Tomalak as he pointed out the actual issue first.

Comment: OK, guys, decide who writes the answer and I'll accept it (so he'll get the credit).

Comment: Also look at the extension I wrote to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you don't prevent the default action of a form submit - which is to POST data to the server and reload the page. As a side-effect this cancels all running Ajax requests, which causes the effect you see.

To prevent the default event action, call [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event object.

```
function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some processing, for example Ajax
    // the browser will not issue a traditional POST request
}
```

Back in the day, `return false;` had the same effect, but nowadays.`preventDefault()` is the way to go.

---

Further comments on your code:

#### Client Side

Don't roll your own Ajax functions. Ajax libraries are plenty and convenient, well-tested and provide easy-to-read Ajax support that prevents common errors and does all kinds of heavy lifting transparently. Just use one of the [many libraries](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/).

With jQuery, which you seem to be using anyway, the function becomes as straight-forward as this:

```
function addFormToDB(email, company, subject, text) {
    return $.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit", {
            email: email,
            company: company,
            subject: subject,
            text: text
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log("received", data);
            alert("Thank You!");
        })
        .fail(function (jqXhr, status, err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

#### Server Side

Don't do your own promisification. It might look easy enough, but just as with Ajax, there's enough stuff that can go wrong and is easily overlooked. Let a library do it for you, or use a wrapper library that did it for you. For node-sqlite3, one such wrapper library exists: [co-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-sqlite3). I recommend you look at it.

Your code could look like this:

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var q = req.query;
    var params = [q.email, q.company, q.subject, q.text];

    db.serialize()
        .then(() => db.run("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", params))
        .then(() => res.status(200).end())
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(400).end();
        });
    });
});
```

Or use one of the async/yield variants shown in the library's samples.