# Catch an Image Specific Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, error-handling

Im trying to catch when an image fails loading with a specific reason, say, `Denied load of "url"`. I tried using `onerror` but that fires with every error. Is there a way to specify the `onerror` or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in this way

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

now you can call a function on this like,

```
function imgError(image) {
image.onerror = "";
image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
return true;}
```

Comment: Sorry but, that works for all errors too, how can I discriminate between them? My image throws 2 errors, "Denied load of" and "ERR_FAILED", I need the webpage to do different things for each error.

Comment: what are you getting in (image) parameter ?

Comment: i'm getting all the document, i'm guessing because i create the image in a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not posible, but usually the problem is something like this : " Error 404 resource found " or "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ".

But you can make ajax request with type GET and catch the error.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function CheckImageError(img){
    var urlimg = img.attributes.src.ownerElement.currentSrc ;
    $.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:urlimg ,
            context: img,
     error:function(requestObject, error, errorThrown){
       // trace console.log or other action 
     },
     complete: function(){
      //do something
                 $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
     }
    })
   }  
</script>

<img onerror="CheckImageError(this)"  src="image.gif">
```

You can check xmlhttpRequest Object properties

[image]

Comment: Okay, i'm trying your solution. Why does currentSrc gives me ""? img.attributes.src.ownerElement gives me the img object with it's src, but currentSrc turns it to "".

Comment: then your ajax request will execute error callback ;)

Comment: Somehow it still executed complete callback. I tried to erase ownerElement.currentSrc and then it executed error but errorThrown was empty, any ideas?

Comment: Okay, i didnt see the screenshot before, my requestObject has status: 0 and statusText: "error". That's not good right?

Comment: If you are testing on local file without server can be the reason.  or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Comment: Yes, i'm testing on a local file