# asp.net web api AJAX status 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a basic REST POST using asp.net Web API, but it is returning error status: 0. Also it looks like fails the AJAX request

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public myData Post( myData m)
    {
        return m;
    }
```

My class:

```
public class CLData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My HTML request:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        //form encoded data
         var dataType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
         var data = $('form').serialize();

         //JSON data
         var dataType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
         var data = {
            FirstName: 'Andrew',
            LastName: 'Lock',
            Age: 31
         }

         console.log('Submitting form...');
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:52884/api/contact',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: dataType,
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('Error: ');
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why my console log is:

```
Submitting form..
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:52884/api/contact. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Error: 
Object with status: 0
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I'm just trying to learn Web API, that's why this example is so simple.

Comment: Just as an experiment, try replacing 'url: 'http://localhost:52884/api/contact' with 'url: '/api/contact'. Assuming that your application is actually hosting both the API endpoint and serving the page. If it is not serving the page, you need to enable cross-origin requests in your application.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not serving up both the web view and the API endpoint, you'll need to enable Cross-Origin-Requests. To do so, you need to configure Cors in your WebAPI project. You can find a detailed breakdown of how to do so on the [Microsoft Reference Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

However, the gist is to install the nuget pacakge `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`. You can do so by executing `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`. From there, you will update your WebApiConfig `Register` method to include `config.EnableCors();` at the top.

Next, you'll decorate your controller class with the `[EnableCors]` attribute. From there, you should be able to make cross-origin requests.

Comment: Thank you. It avoid the Cross-Origin warning, but I'm still getting error from AJAX error method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0 check this out