# jQuery AJAX Calls Returns HTTP Status 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with some users of a web application which makes a number of AJAX calls to update a backend database. Users will enter/scan in a new barcode and when they tab out of the field it will call the AJAX request to silently update the database via a PHP page.

This works 99% of the time but on occasions users are reporting that they get this error message:

```
There was an error updating the Product Barcode - AJAX Request error. HTTP Status: 0
```

Here's the script in question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control.barcode").change(function() {
    var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    var barcode = $(this).val();
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateProduct.php', {
      type: 'updateProduct',
      recid: recid,
      barcode: barcode
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Product Barcode - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the IT Help Desk';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        $("#productBarcodeErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#productBarcodeError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("has-error");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Product Barcode - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the IT Help Desk';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
      $("#productBarcodeErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#productBarcodeError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So it looks like the AJAX request is failing and it's returning an HTTP Status of 0 which doesn't sound like a valid HTTP status (I would expect a 4xx or 500 etc HTTP Status). I'm not sure what the 0 value represents and how I can go about locating the exact cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `dataType = 'json'`? have you tried `stringifying` your object? . Can you take a screenshot of your network tabs for the request / response and add it to the question?

Comment: It seems like a backend issue, this script is fine nothing wrong with it... Try to check updateProduct.php file for errors instead

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0) might give some clues.