# Laravel: AJAX status 0 for internal requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-passport

On the same Laravel project, I have an API at `localhost:8000/api` and a website at `localhost:8000/admin`. When I send the following request from the website, which is supposed to return a list of partners in JSON, it returns a status 0:

```
let token = "e9Klj0...";
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost:8000/api/partners",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

According to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0), the different cases of status 0 are:

- unreachable URL: I don't think the problem comes from there, I can access `localhost:8000/api/partners` via Postman.
- intercepted request by the ad blocker: I've disabled uBlock Origin, but it still won't work.
- interrupted request: I don't send any other request than that of AJAX.
- cross-site scripting: I think that's the most likely case but my API and my website run on the same webserver, and AJAX handles internal requests without dealing with the CORS.

How could I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Chances are the problem is in your controller function that handles that route, so post that.

Comment: You can always check the laravel log. It probably contains some more information, like route mismatches or other errors.

Comment: @Loek Where can I find it?

Comment: `projectroot/storage/log/laravel.log` iirc

Comment: @LukeRamsden No matter the code of the `index()` function of `PartnerController` (I could very well put `return response()->json(null,200);`) nothing changes.

Comment: @Loek The last entry of the log is from several hours ago, I don't think there is anything of importance in it. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: Go in your server and make sure it is receiving the request. Is it receiving it? If so, you are not responding properly. If not, your server is not receiving it (obviously), and might be a middleware/route/ui issue.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: You have `/api/partners` defined in your server, right? Go to the controller that is defined for that route, and just make sure it is being hit. Do a `var_dump('foo')` or something like that.

Comment: url: "/api/partners" try this

Comment: Is the request type `get` ? or `post`? Since you are sending the token, I assume it's `post` in that case you better specify as `post` and send a dummy `data` which then in your server check for it