# Why does my Jquery Ajax call fail with error 0?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an ajax request using the below code but I keep getting an Error 0 message. I am pretty sure the url is valid but I just wondered if the code is ok as I am trying this for the first time, altering a template provided by a tutor. Any advice gratefully received.

```
     $('#submitOne').click(function() {

       $.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/alistairJenkins/task/php/getCountryCode.php",
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             lat: $('#latOne').val(),
             lng: $('#lngOne').val()
         }})
        .done(function(result) {

             console.log(result);

             if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                 $('#txtResult').html(result['data']);
             }
         })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 var errorMsg = jqXHR.status + ' : ' + textStatus + errorThrown;
                 alert("Error - " + errorMsg);
         })
      })
```

Comment: You're likely getting a CORS error. Review the console and network tabs in developer tools.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. So how do I fix that - adding something in my Jquery - or adding something in the php file its sending the request to?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - figured out how to add the header in my php file. Thanks for getting me past that hurdle. Now to tackle the new error I am getting! If you could add this as an answer so I can accept it and close the question that would be good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is AJAX returning HTTP status code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/why-is-ajax-returning-http-status-code-0)

Comment: Didn't figure you were the first to ask, or I was the first to answer :). You can see the answer in [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016085/215552), where it mentions "cross-site scripting"; it refers to CORS in the comments as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working snippet that demonstrates the use of `$.ajax()` with a public JSON resource:

```js
$('#submitOne').click(function() {

       $.ajax({
         // url: "http://localhost/alistairJenkins/task/php/getCountryCode.php",
         url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             lat: $('#latOne').val(),
             lng: $('#lngOne').val()
         }}) 
        .done(function(result, textStatus, xhr) {

             console.log(result);

             if (xhr.status===201) $('#txtResult').text(result.id);
         })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 var errorMsg = jqXHR.status + ' : ' + textStatus + errorThrown;
                 alert("Error - " + errorMsg);
         }) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="latOne" value="52.373920">  <input id="lngOne" value="9.735603"> 
<button id="submitOne">go</button><br>
<div id="txtResult"></div>
```

The `.status` property can be found in the `xhr` object (the third argument of the callback function in the `.done()` event handler). The value `201` signals success.